# How to implement a navigation controller within a child fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I have a navigation controller fragment defined inside my activity_main that has a match height and width of parent. So when I navigate between fragments, it replaces the entire screen. Now say I navigate to a fragment that loads up a material card. I want that material card to have its own navigation controller that takes up the height and width of the material card. So when I use its navigation controller, it will only replace fragments within the material card view and not change the parent's view.

Is there a way to have two navigation host fragments? So I can define one inside activity_main and then another one that I can define inside the child fragment.

activity_main:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/base_nav_graph" />
```

childfragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_child_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/child_nav_graph" />
```

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

See advanced sample 
https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample

There used multiple navigation controllers for BottomNavigationView items